# Evenly distributing a timeline in some length even when length is less than the number of points (compression)

Tags: algorithm, math, calendar

I need to render a horizontal calendar and render events on it. So I get two dates and the width in pixels. I want to distribute the days between the two provided dates over those pixels and maintain a minimum distance between the visual points.

for instance, I have 365 days (each day should consume at least 10 pixels) and I need to distribute then over 300 pixels. So I need to "pack" them in groups so each pixel would represent multiple dates. How can I calculate this mathematically speaking?

i.e.

```
(days)
1/1    8/1    16/1    24/1    2/2    10/2    18/2    ......
```

in the above example for instance, how can I calculate that I need to "pack/skip" the 7 days?

What I need in the end is to produce an array with the dates (days) and the x offset where it should be positioned in the horizontal axis.

```
i.e.
1/1/2013 = 0
2/1/2013 = 0
3/1/2013 = 0
4/1/2013 = 0
5/1/2013 = 0
6/1/2013 = 0
7/1/2013 = 0
8/1/2013 = 10
9/1/2013 = 10
10/1/2013 = 10
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 300 pixels to use. Each 'package' should be at least 10 pixels. This means you should have 300/10=30 packages. You have 365 which should be distributed over 30 packages so that's 365/30=12.17 days per package. Or simply 12.
The same logic can be used to calculate the amount of days needed in a package if you have a different amount of pixels to use.
I hope that this was what you were asking for.

Jannes

Edit: I have just read your edit so I will alter my reply a bit here.
If you have converted your date to a number between 1 and 365 you can simply calculate each element of your array days like this.

```
days[i]=floor(i/12)*10
```

Where the 12 came from above calculations.

Answer (score 0):

```
date_width = 10
display_width = 300
date_range = 365

num_of_dates = display_len // date_len
date_offsets = [x * date_range // num_of_dates for x in range(num_of_dates)]
```

gives dates for every 10 "pixels"

```
[0, 12, 24, 36, 48, 60, 73, 85, 97, 109, 121, 133, 146, 158, 170, 182, 194, 206, 219, 231, 243, 255, 267, 279, 292, 304, 316, 328, 340, 352]
```

if seeing that you have about 12 days between data points you want to shift it up to 2 weeks

```
date_offset = 14
date_offsets = [x * date_offset for x in range(date_range//date_offset)]
date_positions = [display_width * o // date_range for o in date_offsets]
```